# How do I setup PyDev 2.7 in Aptana Studio 3? (Windows 8)

Tags: python, pydev, aptana

I am trying to follow a tutorial on Python that uses Aptana Studio 3 and PyDev 2.7, but Aptana is defaulting to PyDev 3.0.  How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

The PyDev version bundled with Aptana cannot be changed... to change it you have to use a base Eclipse install and install only PyDev there.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate your help!